# Integral of function of sin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is the following true?

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho = 2 \int_{-0.5\pi}^{0.5\pi} f(x-\sin(\omega))d\omega$

If so, would appreciate it if someone could show how we get to the RHS?

Cheers

Comment: Not true.  Let $x=0$ and $f(x)=x$--the LHS is zero, but the RHS is not.

Comment: in the case you described where x=0 and f(x)=x ,  RHS would also be zero so the equality holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho=\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2}f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho+\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho
$$
Now change variable in the first integral $\omega=-\rho-\pi$. Then $d\rho=-d\omega$, $$\sin(\rho)=\sin(-\omega-\pi)=-\sin(\omega+\pi)=\sin(\omega)$$
The integration limits are now from $-(-\pi)-\pi=0$ to $-(-\pi/2)-\pi=-\pi/2$. Then
$$\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2}f(x-\sin(\rho))d\rho=-\int_{0}^{-\pi/2}f(x-\sin(\omega))d\omega=\int_{-\pi/2}^0f(x-\sin(\omega))d\omega$$
You can do the same for the last integral.